# Getting code compiler errors on Mac but not windows learning how to code

Tags: c++

```
#include iostream

using namespace std;

int main (){

int x = {5};

int width {};

cout<<x;

cout<<"Hello World";

return 0;


}
```

this is my error

```
Helloworld.cpp:8:10: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
int width {};
         ^
         ;
1 error generated.
```

I copied this same code on my windows laptop and it compiles perfect but not on Mac m1
I noticed x, width, and the word cost are blue on Mac but white on windows
yes the iostream is

Comment: i'm guessing this comes down to the compilers used...

Comment: Your compiler either doesn't support C++11, or isn't configured to use it.

Comment: so how would I change this both myth vscode settings on my Mac and windows are synced and the same. I just want to learn using my Mac instead but having trouble with issues like this

Comment: macOS clang++ defaults to C++98. Pass `-std=c++11` as a compiler flag. It's best practice to always specify the version C++ you are compiling against over the wish and prayer that is the compiler default.

Comment: where do I pass that flag in vscode settings ?

Comment: `tasks.json` would be my first guess; depends on how you're building. You also want to set the Intellisense to whatever version you're compiling for.

Comment: Or, you could simply write code that works in older C++ versions, eg: `int x = 5; int width = 0;` Also, `#include iostream` should be `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what this program is meant to do, but I am assuming you are trying to declare another variable (width). I rewrote the code for you below.

```
#include <iostream> // You need to put the header in <>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int x = 5; // You don't need the {}
int width; // I'm assuming you want this variable to be without a value or you want it to be changed by the user

cout << x << endl; // Add endl; if you want to say something on mac and that the end of the program or you'll end up with a % at the end. I use mac so...

cin >> width; // cin means user input so you can change the value of width

cout << width << endl; // Just shows width variable

cout << "Hello World" << endl; // You can remove this if you don't want it to say hello world.

return 0; // You don't need this in recent version, you can include it though

}
```